# Add MKCircle to Map

Tags: swift

I have a problem with the `MKCircle`.
My goal is to create a circle around the current position of the user.

Can anyone help me to add the circle to the map?
I tried to add it as an overlay, however I can't see anything on the map.

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: map.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,
        longitude: map.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

let rad = CLLocationDistance(1000)

map.delegate = self

map.addOverlay(MKCircle(centerCoordinate: center, radius: rad))
```

Answer (score 1):

An overlay is not, of itself, a visible thing. Without an implementation of `mapView:rendererForOverlay:`, you may expect to see exactly what you are seeing — nothing. It is up to you to implement this method to return an MKCircleRenderer to draw the actual circle on the map.